# Tag cleanup: probability and statistics

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Thanks to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88178/121) I became aware of the fact that we have (at least) these overlapping tags:

- [probability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [probability-and-stats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-and-stats)
- [statistics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

Are "probability" and "statistics" sufficiently differentiated to keep each of those tags and eliminate [probability-and-stats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-and-stats) or should all of these tags be made synonymous hereafter?

Comment: I'm still confused with that myself; IIRC, back when we were still in beta, I seem to have seen an agreement that we use the second tag up until it can be justified that a split is necessary. Maybe now's the time to reconsider.

Comment: [What's the difference between probability and statistics?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/665/whats-the-difference-between-probability-and-statistics)

Comment: I'm sure the folks at Cross Validated could come up with a good justification, but I think the question for us is: does *Mathematica* sufficiently differential probability and statistics to warrant different tags.  Offhand, I can't think of a family of functions or a MMA paradigm that falls into one category but not the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion [probability-and-stats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-and-stats) should be replaced by 
[probability-and-statistics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-and-statistics) with the synonyms [probability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) and [statistics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics). The difference between [probability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) and [statistics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) becomes too blurred when using *Mathematica* to justify having them as separate tags. For example, one might want to characterize a random process (probability theory) and therefore creates a set of random data from this process and then processes this data (statistics). The difference also vanishes when using [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your position.

Comment: I have merged `probability` and `statistics` into `probability-and-stats` but I ran into a problem after that:  `probability-and-statistics` is one character too long.  I'll use `probability-or-statistics` if you do not have a better idea.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, "one character too long" - that's why we had the "stats" in the tag. :)

Comment: @Guess Yeah, figured as much.  Is keeping that as-is your preferred option?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, well, the only selling point of "or" is that "statistics" is written out in full. I could swing with that unless somebody else has a better idea.

Comment: As a statistician I prefer having statistics spelled out rather than abbreviated.  How about statistics-and-prob ? ;)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That arbitrary character limit should just be increased by one.

Comment: @Karsten I don't have that ability, and I imagine this is a network-wide limitation and unlikely to be changed.  I could also do `probability--statistics` with two hyphens; I don't know if that's better or worse than "-or-".